# Find the last stop time in a series of action sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a player that will play a video. User can start or stop the video.

Each time user plays video, it will be a video_click_id. I would like to find out id of first stop in the series of stop that ends the video. If video_click_id ends with one stop, get the last stop. If video_click_id ends with two stop, get the second last stop. If video_click_id ends with 3 stop, get the 3rd last stop.

```
   id          video_click_id action_timestamp          action
   ----------- ------------- -----------------------   ------
   3           1             2016-05-19 13:59:07.437   play
   4           1             2016-05-19 13:59:13.413   stop
   6           1             2016-05-19 15:59:40.213   stop
   8           2             2016-05-19 16:29:11.950   play
   9           2             2016-05-19 16:29:27.090   stop
   10          2             2016-05-19 16:29:28.000   play
   12          2             2016-05-19 16:29:29.390   stop
   13          3             2016-05-19 20:59:07.437   play
   14          3             2016-05-19 20:59:13.413   stop
   15          3             2016-05-19 20:59:40.213   stop
   26          3             2016-05-19 20:59:40.213   stop
```

1. In this case, result id of video_click_id 1 will be 4.
2. Result id of video_click_id 2 will be 12.
3. Result id of video_click_id 3 will be 14.

Can anyone help me? I am using mssql.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is maximum of two stops ? or it can be more than 2 ?

Comment: Hi, it can be more then two. But it should get the first stop for the series of stop that ends the video.

Comment: Your question makes no sense after the update.  Now click group 1 ends in `stop` and click group 2 ends in `play`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your comment. I edited the question again.

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: Hi Zohar, microsoft sql server 2012

Comment: Building on @TimBiegeleisen's answer, I came up with [this](http://rextester.com/EYKZ40998). Giving Tim a chance to update his answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Go for the bacon and post (despite it not being kosher), don't let me stand in your way :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well I do love bacon :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the query below, the subquery assigns a row number to every `stop` record.  Then, the outer query retains the first stop record for each `video_click_id` group.

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.video_click_id,
    t.action_timestamp,
    t.action
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY video_click_id ORDER BY action_timestamp) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE action = 'stop'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Hi, Tim. Thanks so much for the answer! It helps for me to refer. Possibly there is stop action at the middle of the video. Let me change the example a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` to retrieve all stops that are *not* followed by a play. Then you can use a `group by` to select the earliest `id` of the stop that was *not* followed by a play:

```
select min(id), video_click_id
from mytable t1
where action = 'stop'
and not exists ( -- subquery ensures that no 'play' occurs after 'stop'
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.video_click_id = t1.video_click_id
    and t2.action = 'play'
    and t2.id > t1.id
) group by video_click_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **id** is incremental, you can use the following simple query for the desired output -

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, video_click_id
FROM
(
    SELECT *
     , LAG(action) OVER(PARTITION BY video_click_id ORDER BY action_timestamp) AS prev_action
    FROM MyTable
) AS p
WHERE action = 'stop' AND prev_action = 'play'
GROUP BY video_click_id;
```

The subquery finds the previous action for each action. We want the 'stop' action immediately after the last 'play' action. So selecting the maximum value of id will get the id where the video actually stopped.

[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/234b5/12)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Tim's answer was correct for the first version of the question, but after the question was edited, it needed a minor adjustment - adding a not exists to the derived table did the trick:

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.video_click_id,
    t.action_timestamp,
    t.action
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY video_click_id ORDER BY action_timestamp) rn
    FROM yourTable t0
    WHERE action = 'stop'
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM yourTable t1
        WHERE t1.video_click_id = t0.video_click_id 
        AND t1.action = 'play'
        AND t1.action_timestamp > t0.action_timestamp
    )
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Output:

```
id  video_click_id  action_timestamp            action
4   1               2016-05-19 13:59:13.413     stop
12  2               2016-05-19 16:29:29.390     stop
14  3               2016-05-19 20:59:13.413     stop
```

[Rextester link](http://rextester.com/EYKZ40998)